# I want to open UIView just like facebook opens image in fullscreen in objective c

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiview

I have tried a lot but not getting any solution . I have referd https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLMediaZoom .

Comment: how you are use this library? download zip from github and run or implement pod in your project?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of third party libraries, https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/vertigo seems to do what you want? You could look on https://www.cocoacontrols.com/ for others, like https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/exphotoviewer.

If you want to implement this yourself, you could look at custom transitions which became possible in iOS 7, e.g. when you tap a UIView, you transition to a UIViewController which covers the fullscreen with the image.

Actually that being said you could just animate your UIView to cover the fullscreen :p,

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
// (flag) ? set frame fullscreen : set frame normal


// or even better create and modify constraints with Masonry 
// https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry :)
}];
```